# Concurrency settings of my RedisSpider doesn't performance as expected

Tags: python, concurrency, scrapy

I wrote a spider with scrapy-redis and python3.7.
I set **CONCURRENT_REQUESTS** to 10.
Here is my settings of the spider:

```
    custom_settings = {
        "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {
            "projects.middlewares.MediaFileCheckMiddleware": 300,
        },
        "DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT": 300,
        "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": 10,
        "SCHEDULER_PERSIST": True,
        "SCHEDULER_FLUSH_ON_START": False,
        "SCHEDULER_IDLE_BEFORE_CLOSE": 0,
    }
```

I expect it could handle 10 download requests at the same time like multi-threads and each thread could start a new request immediately while the prevous one is done.

The fact is, the spider got 10 requests from redis at one time and downloaded them, but it didn't get a new request until the prevous 10 were all done.

What I expect is:

thread1 --job1--|-----job2-----|-job3-|--job4--|...
thread2 ----job1----|----job2----|----job3----|...
thread3 -job1-|-job2-|----job3----|--job4--|...

What I saw is:

thread1 --job1--      |-----job2-----|-job3-         |--job4--,...
thread2 ----job1----|----job2----   |----job3----|...
thread3 -job1-         |-job2-           |----job3---- |--job4--,...

I don't understand why..

The main code:

```
class FileHandler(RedisSpider):
  name = 'filehandler'
  redis_key = 'news:multimedias'
  file_path = r'/data/temp'
  img_header = Headers(content_type='img')

  size_limit = 50 * 1024 * 1024

  custom_settings = {
      "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {
          "projects.dapoo.middlewares.MediaFileCheckMiddleware": 300,
      },
      "DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT": 300,
      # "DOWNLOAD_WARNSIZE": 0,
      "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": 10,
      "SCHEDULER_PERSIST": True,
      "SCHEDULER_FLUSH_ON_START": False,
      "SCHEDULER_IDLE_BEFORE_CLOSE": 0,
  }

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def make_request_from_data(self, data):
      obj = json.loads(data)
      suffix = obj.get('suffix')
      src = obj.get("src")
      err = obj.get('err')
      media_type = obj.get('media_type')

      if err:
          pass  # logging
      else:
          return scrapy.Request(
              src,
              method="GET",
              headers=self.img_header(),
              dont_filter=True,
              meta={'file_name': str(int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()))},
              callback=self.parse
          )

  def parse(self, response):
      file_name = response.meta.get('file_name')
      file_path = os.path.join(self.file_path, file_name)
      with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
          f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: @Alexander code added. Thx for reminding me.